Cannot use variable from template file as AWS service connection in Azure YAML pipeline
I am using variable templates to hold information about different environments. Each environment uses a different AWS service connection, so in each variable file it has a different value, e.g.:
env-us.yml:

variables:
  EnvName: US
  AwsCredentials: 'AzureDevOps(us-2)'

In the pipeline YAML I then try to use this variable as follows:
 - stage: Push 
   variables: 
     - template: env-us.yml
   jobs: 
   - job: Push 
     steps:
     - task: AWSShellScript@1
       displayName: 'Login'
       inputs:
         awsCredentials: $(AwsCredentials)
         regionName: eu-west-1
         scriptType: 'inline'
         inlineScript: |
            # do stuff

This gives me an error, saying that '$(AwsCredentials)' isn't a valid service connection. If I try $[variables.AwsCredentials] I get the same issue. So it appears not to be expanding the variable.
Any ideas?
I am expecting it to replace $(AwsCredentials) with the value from the variable template file.

The syntax to use in this case is:
awsCredentials: ${{ variables.AwsCredentials}}

See the documentation.
Edit after update in comment
It seems that, because you're injecting the variables in one template and use them in the main pipeline file, the variable cannot be expanded at compile time, so the expression is empty.
So in this case, the macro syntax $(AwsCredentials) should work, because it's evaluated at runtime.
I reproduced a small example and could see the proper values:
vars.yml

variables:
  awsCredential: 'AwsUs'

pipeline.yml

stages:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      variable_file: vars.yml
      my_step_list:
        - script: |
            echo $(awsCredential) <-- macro syntax because variable is injected in template.yml

  - stage: MyStage2
    variables:
      - template: vars.yml
    jobs:
    - job: MyJob
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo ${{ variables.awsCredential }} <-- template expression because variable is injected in same file

template.yml

parameters:
- name: variable_file
  type: string
- name: my_step_list
  type: stepList

stages:
- stage: MyStage
  variables:
    - template: ${{ parameters.variable_file }}
  jobs:
  - job: MyJob
    steps:
      - ${{ parameters.my_step_list }}

If you don't get the expected value, you can check the azure-pipeline-expanded.yaml file from the pipeline logs, from the run detail page after it's finished.

You should see something like that in the file:
stages:
- stage: MyStage
  variables:
  - name: awsCredential <-- variable was properly injected
    value: 'AwsUs'


Hi - many thanks. That has solved the issue in all but one circumstance. It's quite complex but will do my best to explain... see answer below

Colin's answer works in all but one situation. It's quite complex... slightly simplified version below:
env-us.yml:

variables:
  EnvName: US
  AwsCredentials: 'AzureDevOps(us-2)'

pipeline.yml:

parameters:
- name: envs 
  type: object 
  default: 
  - "us" 
  - "stg"

stages: 
  - ${{ each env in parameters.envs }}:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        variable_file: env-${{ env }}.yml
        my_step_list: 
          - task: AWSShellScript@1
            inputs:
              awsCredentials: ${{ variables.AwsCredentials }}
              regionName: $(AwsRegion)
              scriptType: 'inline'
              failOnStandardError: true
              inlineScript: |
                # doStuff

template.yml:

parameters:
- name: variable_file
  type: string
- name: my_step_list
  type: stepList

stages:
- stage: MyStage
  variables:
    - template: ${{ parameters.variable_file }}
  jobs: 
  - job: MyJob
    steps: 
    - ${{ parameters.my_step_list }}

Works OK for tasks specified inside the template.yml, but since the step list is defined at the top pipeline.yml level it seems to behave differently - the ${{ variables.AwsCredentials }} returns blank.
